# When exactly does the TCP handshake occur in a XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, tcp, network-programming, xmlhttprequest, handshake

The [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) interface provides both an `open()` and a `send()` method.

In the following sample code:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', '/server', true);

xhr.onload = function () {
  // Request finished. Do processing here.
};

xhr.send('string');
```

Does the TCP handshake occur when `send()` is invoked, or `open()`?

Comment: You can't call `send()` multiple times on the same XHR.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks, question updated to reflect that

Comment: I'd expect it when `send()` is called. Note that because of persistent connections, it might reuse a connection from a previous XMLHttpRequest, so there won't be a new handshake.

Comment: Why don't you just run a packet capture to see when it happens?

Comment: @Barmar I'd gladly do that if I knew how

Comment: Use a program like Wireshark or tcpdump.

Comment: Why does it matter? There's not usually much time between open and send.

Comment: Notice that you don't get a "Connection refused" error when there's no server running until you call `send`. That strongly suggests it's when the handshake happens.

Comment: After looking through protocol specs, a `network task` is not queued until the request body is completely parsed. That implies that `send()` is the answer since there is no body until that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only with HTTP version less than 1.1 are the lifetimes of requests and their underlying connection directly related.

The lifetime of the HTTP request is independent of the lifetime of its underlying connection since HTTP 1.1. Many requests can be pipelined down a single connection.

`XMLHttpRequest.open` is an abstraction that is convenient for the user, but under-the-hood, if the browser already has available sockets connected to the host, they can be reused, meaning that the TCP handshake happened some time ago, independently of all but the first request that passed through the connection.

Answer (score 0):

Some brief testing with `tcpdump` verified what has been suspected in the comments. No network calls are made at all when `open()` is called. All network information is transmitted when `send()` is invoked.

In addition, there is no guarantee that `send()` performs the handshake either. `XMLHttpRequest`s sometimes reuse persistent connections from previous requests, and as such don't require a new handshake.